# how to replaced the scroll bar in list view by a buttons can scroll the items in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

hello i am try to create a project has a list view and its items sorted horizantly and i want to disabled the scroll bar of the list and replaced by 2 buttons on of them make the items go to right and the other make the items go to left [that what i try to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McKWH.png)
i read this code in an article but it give an error

```
private void next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ls.SelectedIndex == -1 || ls.SelectedIndex == ls.Items.Count - 1)
            return;

        Object select, next, temp;
        select = ls.Items[ls.SelectedIndex];
        next = ls.Items[ls.SelectedIndex + 1];

        temp = select;
        select = next;
        next = temp;

        ls.Items[ls.SelectedIndex] = select;
        ls.Items[ls.SelectedIndex + 1] = next;

        ls.SelectedIndex++;
    }

    private void back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ls.SelectedIndex == -1 || ls.SelectedIndex == 0)
            return;

        Object select, previous, temp;
        select = ls.Items[ls.SelectedIndex];
        previous = ls.Items[ls.SelectedIndex - 1];

        temp = select;
        select = previous;
        previous = temp;

        ls.Items[ls.SelectedIndex] = select;
        ls.Items[ls.SelectedIndex - 1] = previous;

        ls.SelectedIndex--;
    }
```

so is there any solution

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

To change the ListView, create a style like this:

```
        <Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="VerticalListView">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />

            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />

            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="None" />

            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="400" />
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

So you can apply the style in xaml like this:

```
<ListView Style="{StaticResource VerticalListView}" />
```

To select itens by code, you can use listView.SelectedIndex property.
For example, to go forward:

```
if (myListView.SelectedIndex+1 > myListView.Items.Count)
{
   myListView.SelectedIndex=0;
}
else
{
  myListView.SelectedIndex++;
}

myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.Items[myListView.SelectedIndex]);
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: can i do it all in c# i'm new to xaml and i didnt understand ur code well :S